# "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)" after upgrading to Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, browser, visual-studio-2013, unauthorized

I have installed Visual Studio 2013. When I try launching my ASP.NET website using vs2013 environment I get a whole bunch of following error for the front-end resources:

**"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)"**

The website launches just fine when using vs 2012. Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Solution explorer click on your project, press <kbd>F4</kbd> and set the property '`Anonymous Authentication`' to **Enabled**.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would also add this additional information regarding this error.

Many of us probably copy code objects from one solution to another. We then change the 'Inherits' parameter on our imported 'ascx' or 'aspx' file so that it now references the new solution.

What I keep forgetting to do is to also change the reference that is on the Class parameter in the mark-up for 'asmx' web service files because it is not as obvious as the mark-up for other files. To do this in Visual Studio 2013 - right click on the asmx file and then choose 'View Markup' from the pop-up context menu.